# How to "flutter pub run build_runner build" with the class has field Timestamp in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, timestamp

I am trying to use the cmd "flutter pub run build_runner build" to serialize the JSON format from object but it keeps plaining with the message:

Error running JsonSerializableGenerator
Could not generate `fromJson` code for `timeTaking`.
None of the provided `TypeHelper` instances support the defined type.

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class RequestData {
  @JsonKey(required: true)
  String uid;
  String phone;
  String email;
  String description;
  /// Tell json_serializable that "owner_name" should be
  /// mapped to this property.
  @JsonKey(name: 'owner-name')
  String ownerName;
  @JsonKey(name: 'location-detail')
  String locationDetail;
  int status;// 0 waiting, 1 accepted, 2 done, 3 DOING , 4 cancel
  List<String> imageUrls;
  @JsonKey( required: true, name: "time-taking", toJson: _timestampToJson/*,fromJson: _timeStampFromJson*/)
  Timestamp timeTaking;

  RequestData({this.uid, this.phone, this.email, this.description,
      this.ownerName, this.locationDetail, this.status, this.imageUrls,this.timeTaking});

  RequestData.none();
}
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue, my temporary solution is create a JsonConverter to convert to DateTime:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

class TimestampConvertDatetime  implements JsonConverter<DateTime, Timestamp> {
  const TimestampConvertDatetime();
  @override
  DateTime fromJson(Timestamp json) {
    return json.toDate();
  }

  @override
  Timestamp toJson(DateTime object) {
    return Timestamp.fromDate(object);
  }
}
```

And apply on your model:

```
...
@TimestampConvertDatetime()
DateTime date;
....
```

Comment: Cool! Let's try this solution.